# Is there a way to have a single instance of a service per an instance of another service without Owned<T>?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm writing a desktop application in C# and using Autofac for DI.
In my app I want to have a big service that depends on several smaller services that depend on each other. There should be only one instance of each of the smaller service per big service:

```cs
class SmallServiceA
{

}
class SmallServiceB
{
    public SmallServiceA serviceA;
    public SmallServiceB(SmallServiceA serviceA)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }
}
class BigService
{
    public SmallServiceA serviceA;
    public SmallServiceB serviceB;
    public BigService(SmallServiceA serviceA, SmallServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }
}
```

```cs
var bigService1 = container.Resolve<BigService>();
Debug.Assert(bigService1.serviceA == bigService1.serviceB.serviceA);
var bigService2 = container.Resolve<BigService>();
Debug.Assert(bigService2.serviceA == bigService2.serviceB.serviceA);
Debug.Assert(bigService1.serviceA != bigService2.serviceA);
```

I've read in the docs that I can use lifetime scopes and `Owned<T>` for this. But the problem is that I need to manually dispose of these. I don't want to put the disposal code in the services because it is purely needed for Autofac and the services shouldn't have anything to do with it.
I can just create the lifetime scope and never dispose of it but it would leak memory.
I can also make it so `BigService` gets `Func<SmallSeriviceA, SmallServiceB>` instead of `SmallServiceB` in the constructor but it would get very messy with more services.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Owned` in case of scoped registrations, though you will need the scope management. Register all required services as [`InstancePerLifetimeScope`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope):

```cs
builder.RegisterType<BigService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<SmallServiceA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<SmallServiceB>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And then create scopes when needed:

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
using (var scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var bigService1 = scope.Resolve<BigService>();
  var bigService2 = scope1.Resolve<BigService>();
  // asserts
}
```

Comment: I want everything to be done automatically when the `BigService` is created and injected into some other service so I can't just do `using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();`. The code in the question was an example of how the services should be resolved.

Comment: @aelsi2 without seeing the whole app structure it is hard to tell. But I can't think of other options (except of the third one -  bubble up the scope so it is managed on higher level than "some other service"'s).

Comment: @aelsi2 _"The code in the question was an example of how the services should be resolved."_ - then you are out of options basically. The only alternative I can see  - manage the scopes and resolution of dependencies inside the `BigService`, so there is no need to propagate the disposes to other dependencies.

Comment: More specifically, I'm working on an application with multiple panels that can be opened and closed. Each panel has its own undo stack and a hierarchy of view models that should depend on the same undo stack. I could add a `Closing` event to the panel interface. Then I would make it so the lifetime scope is created during the panel's resolution and its dispose method is added to `Closing` .

Comment: @aelsi2 yes, this approach sound like something I would try to do.

Comment: _Each panel has its own undo stack and a hierarchy of view models that should depend on the same undo stack._  Is this trying to use DI as if it's a composite data structure?

Comment: @AndrewS I don't understand. Am I doing something wrong? A panel may have a list of child view models that all depend on the same undo stack associated with the panel. These view models may also have more sub- view models that also depend on the same undo stack that belongs to the panel.

Comment: It's not clear why each big service instance needs its own smaller services instances.  I thought that perhaps it was related to the undo stack, etc. used by each panel, and trying to use DI as sort of a meta data structure.  I don't understand the connection between the data structure and the DI services setup.

Comment: Agree, the only way to avoid Owned is to use lifetime scopes oneself. However, this worries me: "I don't want to put the disposal code in the services because it is purely needed for Autofac." If this was being written without DI at all, these services would still have to be disposed and the code would need to be there - it has nothing to do with Autofac. If nothing needs to be disposed, then you don't have to add IDisposable support just to use Owned.

Comment: @AndrewS The undo stack is one of the smaller services that needs to be shared. The panel is the big service. There should be one undo stack (small service) per panel (big service). There are also other objects (unique or not) in the panel that depend on the same stack and push undoable actions into it when their properties are changed.